# Azure SQL Data Warehouse Node to Node Encryption

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

would like to know if there's any encryption in Azure SQL Data Warehouse particularly around inter-node communications during query transits?
If so, could someone help direct me to the page with more info about it?

Comment: Hi Bradley Yoo, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse has the encryption called Transparent data encryption.

You can use Transparent data encryption for your Azure SQL data Warehouse.

Transparent data encryption (TDE) helps protect Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Data Warehouse against the threat of malicious offline activity by encrypting data at rest. It performs real-time encryption and decryption of the database, associated backups, and transaction log files at rest without requiring changes to the application. By default, TDE is enabled for all newly deployed Azure SQL databases.

TDE needs to be manually enabled for older databases of Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, or Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

For more details, please see: [Transparent data encryption for SQL Database and Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-azure-sql).

Reference tutorials:

1. [Portal: Get started with Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) in SQL
   Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-encryption-tde)
2. [T-SQL: Get started with Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-encryption-tde-tsql)

Hope this helps.